# Move items up or down in an associative array list php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I want to know what **I can do to move items in an associative array 'up or down' by one for example for this array :**

```
 Array ( [list] => 
      Array ( [Name1] => 1, 
              [Name2] => 1, 
              [Name3] => 1, 
              [Name4] => 1, 
              [Name5] => 1,  )
 )
```

I know how to do it in a `non-associative array` in this way :

```
   $a = array('a','b','c','d','e');

   function down($a,$x) {
     if( count($a)-1 > $x ) {
    $b = array_slice($a,0,$x,true);
    $b[] = $a[$x+1];
    $b[] = $a[$x];
    $b += array_slice($a,$x+2,count($a),true);
    return($b);
     } else { 
            return $a; 
         }
   }

 function up($a,$x) {
   if( $x > 0 and $x < count($a) ) {
    $b = array_slice($a,0,($x-1),true);
    $b[] = $a[$x];
    $b[] = $a[$x-1];
    $b += array_slice($a,($x+1),count($a),true);
    return($b);
   } else { 
            return $a; 
       }
 }

  //Use 

  // Move item 4 up
  print_r(up($a,4));
```

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: View this link may be help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: I want for example if i want to up the third element i got as results:  Array ( [list] => 
      Array ( [Name1] => 1, 
              [Name3] => 1, 
              [Name2] => 1, 
              [Name4] => 1, 
              [Name5] => 1,  )
 );the same way for down ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$array=array(0=>'name1', 1=>'name2', 2=>'name3', 3=>'name4', 4=>'name5');

function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
}
moveElement($array, 3, 1);

print_r($array);

Result :

Array ( [0] => name1 [1] => name4 [2] => name2 [3] => name3 [4] => name5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your query you want to enter values in associative array it goes like this 
In associative array every value uses a key its like a number for a value.

```
$key => $value
```

suppose `key` is `1` and value is `'Mohit'`
so it will be like `1 => Mohit`
and your query take a variable `$key=0`;
then `$value` is an array of values such as

```
$value = { 'Mohit','Nick','John' }

$key=0;
foreach($value as $val)
{
    $key => $val;
    $key++;
}
```

like this we can make a new associative array.